# DataTables does not display filter button

Tags: javascript, html, datatables

I have a problem, and that is that it does not show me the filter btn, I already produced the links, and I do not understand what the problem is, I will upload the links of whatever you call them, maybe there is some kind of error in the call, in advance, thank you very much!  :

Head :

```html
<!--Styles Css main -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/main.css">
    <!--Styles btns Datatables -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.5/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
    <!--Boostrap Datatables Css  -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.css">
    <!--Favicon -->

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../../assets/img/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon">
```

Scripts :

```html
 <!--====== Scripts -->
    <!--Jquery -->
    <script src="../../js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

    <!--SweetAlert2 -->
    <script src="../../js/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>

    <!--Boostrap js -->
    <script src="../../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!--Jquery ScrollBar -->
    <script src="../../js/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script>

    <!--Main js -->
    <script src="../../js/main.js"></script>
    <!-- Boostrap Bundle-->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- datatables with bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>

    <!--DataTables btns -->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../datatables/JSZip-2.5.0/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../datatables/pdfmake-0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../datatables/pdfmake-0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../datatables/Buttons-1.5.6/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../datatables/Buttons-1.5.6/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../datatables/Buttons-1.5.6/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Styles in Excel     -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/datatables-buttons-excel-styles@1.1.1/js/buttons.html5.styles.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/datatables-buttons-excel-styles@1.1.1/js/buttons.html5.styles.templates.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `maybe there is some kind of error in the call` Use the developers tool in your browser(Ctrl+Shift+i) to check for errors. The code you share only shows the including of scripts, not the scripts itself that should display the button. But are you sure the ../../ path is correct? Try writing the complete URL to those scripts.

Comment: The question mentions a "filter button". What filter button are you referring to? The only button-related items in the question are DataTables export (not filter) button libraries. You have not shown us your DataTables code. Are you using the [`dom`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) option correctly? Have you researched the various existing questions about [DataTables export button visibility](https://www.google.com/search?q=datatables+buttons+not+displayed+site%253Astackoverflow.com)?

Comment: If you really are asking about a button which performs filtering, you can show us a [mre], so we understand what you are referring to. This will help us to avoid guesswork.